# will_paginate with endless page and activities appending first page only

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, android-activity, scroll, will-paginate

I'm trying to get endless page scrolling to work with my ActivitiesController but all it keeps doing is appending the first page of items. I'm not sure how to get it to load the next pages instead.

**ActivitiesController**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    params[:page] ||= 1
    @activities = Activity.for_member(current_member, params)
  end

end
```

**Activities Model**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :targetable, polymorphic: true

  self.per_page = 4

  def self.for_member(member, options={})
    options[:page] ||= 1
    following_ids = member.following_members.map(&:id).push(member.id)
    where("member_id in (?)", following_ids).
        order("created_at desc").
        page(options[:page])
  end 
end
```

**Endless Page jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100){
            $('.pagination').text("Loading more...");
            $.getScript($('.pagination .next_page').attr('href'));
        }
    });
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#act_index').append('<%= j render ("activities/activities") %>');
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@activities) %>');
```

**Activities Partial**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>

    <%= render partial: "activities/#{activity.targetable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}",
    locals: { activity: activity } %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was missing an 'a' in the jQuery code. So this line:

```
$.getScript($('.pagination .next_page').attr('href'));
```

Needed to be:

```
$.getScript($('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href'));
```